# Issue passing variables in PHP with $_POST

Tags: php, variables

I have a searchresult.php file where I pull all the menus names out of my database and print them with a button close to them where the button has a input type hidden where I associated the name of the menu through the variable $nameofmenu . Something like

Menu1  --> Button (See Menu)

Menu2  --> Button (See Menu)

Menu3  --> Button (See Menu)

```
<?PHP
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $nameofmenu = $myrow[name];
  echo $nameofmenu; //It prints correctly the name of the menu
  echo '<form name"formname" method="post" action="resultsmenu.php">';
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='menuname' value=' $nameofmenu ' />";
 echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='See Menu' />";
}
?>
```

Then I have my resultsmenu.php file that will open when I click in any of the buttons.

```
<?php
  $nameofmenu = $_POST['menuname'];
  $db = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=test user=myuser password=mypass');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM menu where name='$nameofmenu'";
    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }
    $myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $description = $myrow[description];
 ?>
```

I have 2 Issues:

1. First issue: in the searchresult.php, even it prints out correctly all the different menu names, whenever I click any of the buttons, all the buttons return my the same menu (The last one, in the example: Menu 3 in the  $nameofmenu = $_POST['menuname']; of the resultsmenu.php file.
2. Second issue: this issue happend in the resultsmenu.php file. Even for Menu 3, it seams that the recognized the value in the variable. Meaning I don't get back any result or value from the query: $query = "SELECT * FROM menu where name='$nameofmenu'";
   However, if I set up the value Manually like $nameofmenu = "Menu3"; then It works. 
   I even tried this code to see if there is any different in the value passed from $_POST['menuname'] and the value typed in manually and it seams to be the same value because it prints "Both variables are the same"

   ```
   $nameofmenu2 = "Menu3";
   $nameofmenu = $_POST['menuname']; //where the value in menuname is Menu3
    if ($nameofmenu2 = $nameofmenu){echo "Both variables are the same";}
   ```

Thank you so much

Comment: Equality comparison is with `==`, not `=`.  An assignment operation will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: You don't appear to be closing your form, for starters.

Comment: I think the issue is with html, all of you input have same name property, that might cause issue when it send data back to php

Comment: Also, as happens so often, this code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  You should be using prepared statements with query parameters.

Comment: Great!!!! Thank you , the real issue was that I didn't close the </form> some times we need a fresh set of eyes to take a look at things, because I was getting crazy through my code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the same input field (=name) over and over again, so only the "last" overwrite is returned/available. To avoid this, put the data as POST-ARRAYs like this (also switch your quotes):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="menuname[]" value="'.$nameofmenu.'" />';
```

After submitting, you now will see that `$_POST['menuname']` is an `array`! e.g.

```
var_dump($_POST['menuname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by David, your are assigning nameofmenu2 to nameofmenu. But furthermore, when you echoed:

```
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='menuname' value=' $nameofmenu ' />";
```

you included whitespace on either side of $nameofmenu. This could cause problems when you go to make your query. Try using:

```
var_dump($_POST['menuname']);
```

to check your expected post data.